# Use last inserted id as username

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like that whenever i insert a row the newly generated id be used as a username and also get inserted in the user_name field. Any idea on how how i can achieve this will be much appretiated.
I have tried to run the below code on mysql workbench,and everything seem to work fine except for the insert statement.

```
create database if not exists mydatabase;
create table if not exists mydatabase.mytable
(
    id int auto_increment not null,
    user_name int not null,
    pass_word varchar(100),
    primary key(id)
);
insert into mydatabase.mytable(user_name,pass_word) values (select SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'mypass');
```

Comment: if user_name is going ot be exactly the same as Id , what's the point of having a column for that

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function.

Comment: If `user_name` should be an autonumber then why not just define it with `auto_increment` and drop the `id` column... But then why call it a user_*name*? What's in a name anyway, probably not a number...

Comment: My appologies for wasting your time. I am working on a school project and i've been thinking that in a table there should always be an ID field. @eshirvana surely there's no oint for having the ID column.

Comment: Something's not quite right here. Usually a table that hold that kind of information is used for user logins or registrations on some app. I'm sure that the `INSERT` operation only happens on user registration and the username+password value is according to what user typed in. I never had any experience with an app where you can enter password without username (or vice-versa) and I've been assigned with a "generated" username.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your version of sql supports multiple auto_increment columns. However I'm thinking you could either create a trigger or insert the following every time you do an insert:

```
update my_table
set user_name = id
```